# Checking TextCompositionEventArgs.ControlText by Unicode encoding

Tags: c#, unicode, control-characters

I'm looking at a WPF example from a book where `OnPreviewTextInput` is overridden in a class derived from `Window`. The override checks the `TextCompositionEventArgs.ControlText` string against the Unicode literal character `'\u000F'`. This corresponds to the user pressing Ctrl+O.

The character `'\u000F'` looks like a "magic" literal to me. How would I know what to check for if I wanted to check for other codes? Is there a more reader-friendly way to do this?

```cs
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    // Ctrl+O
    if (e.ControlText.Length > 0 && e.ControlText[0] == '\u000F')
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have surmised, it is a "magic" literal. But there is some logic and history behind the magic. It corresponds to an old concept called [Control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (long read, only if you're interested).

For a quick reference of how `0x0F` corresponds to `Ctrl-O`, [see this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives)). Focus on the first column with the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation); you'll see that characters 1-26 (`0x01`-`0x1A`) maps `Ctrl-A` to `Ctrl-Z`. Char 15 (or `0x0F`) is your `Ctrl-O`.

These old ASCII control codes were brought over to Unicode, retaining their mapping. Hence your `'\u0000F'`.

If you've been on the internet long enough you'll see some dumb^H^H^H^Hawesome jokes that rely on the arcane knowledge that `^H` maps to the Backspace control character. You can actually try some of them. Fire up Notepad, and you'll see that `Ctrl-I` and `Ctrl-M` map to Tab and Enter correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` method should make the code more readable:

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    // Ctrl+O
    if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.O))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```